# Using AudioQueue to play PCM audio stream have low volume

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audioqueue

I am having a problem when using AudioQueue to play PCM data. The volume is low when using the iPhone's speaker; I have even turned the system volume up to maximum. However, the volume is fine when I am using the earphones.

I inserted the data into the queue like this:

```
memcpy(mBuffers[mIndex]->mAudioData, pcmData, mBufferByteSize);
mBuffers[mIndex]->mAudioDataByteSize = mBufferByteSize;
mBuffers[mIndex]->mPacketDescriptionCount = mBufferByteSize/2;
OSStatus status = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(mQueue, mBuffers[mIndex], 0, NULL);
NSLog(@"fill audio queue buffer[%d]",mIndex);
if(mIndex == kNumberBuffers - 1) {
    isStartPlay = YES;
    mIndex = 0;
    AudioQueueSetParameter(mQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 1.0);
    status = AudioQueueStart(mQueue, NULL);
}else {
    mIndex++;
}
```

I have set the volume like this:

```
AudioQueueSetParameter(mQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` audio session category? If so, then you're probably playing back through the receiver, which is very quiet.

This bizarre default behaviour harks back to the days when play-and-record category was imagined to be useful mainly for VOIP apps, which, even more strangely, were banned from the AppStore.

To override playback through the normal speaker, try adding `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker` to your category options:

`[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But i am not using any audio session category, just using audio queue for recording and playing PCM audio stream. So i am confusing that why the volume is low when i am using the speaker to play, which will not happen when using earphones.Do you have any idea of that?

Comment: Perhaps you are getting a default record/play and record category? Can you try either the above code or using `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` for playback?

Comment: Yes, i try `[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];` and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Stucked with silent output from AudioQueue and guess what... Initializing  AVAudioSession (not queue!) with
`AVAudioSession *sharedAudioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];[sharedAudioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:nil];`

helped with AudioQueue too!